# .htaccess problem on making a friendly url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Trying to port from `localhost:8080/user/profile.php?id=30`
to `localhost:8080/user/30`

.htaccess file is inside the user folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+) profile.php?id=$1
```

What is actually wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> `.htaccess` file is inside the `user` folder.
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+) profile.php?id=$1
> ```

If the `.htaccess` file is *inside* the `/user` directory then you need to remove `user/` from the start of the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, otherwise, this simply does not match.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

In a *directory* context (ie. `.htaccess`) the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against is less the directory-prefix (the absolute filesystem path of the location of the `.htaccess` file - which also ends in a slash). So, given a request for `/user/30`, the URL that is matched is simply `30` (no slash prefix).

I've also added the end-of-string anchor (`$`) so that it matches `/user/<number>` exactly and not `/user/<number><something>`. You should also include the `L` flag to avoid conflicts with other directives that might follow.